# How can i use laravel echo with sanctum and socket.io and nuxtjs?

Tags: laravel, echo, nuxt.js

How can i use Laravel echo with sanctum and socket.io and nuxt.js? I don't know how to configure it...i get always error 419 in laravel-echo-server. Do you have any idea?